# Python code won't pause

Tags: python

I'm going through Zed Shaw's "Learning Python the hard way" , I'm on exercise 13 and I can't get python to pause so I can see what the code does.

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third

raw_input(' Press enter')
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with your script. You need to call the script with exactly 3 arguments. Otherwise it will throw an error.

For running the application with arguments:

1. Open command prompt
2. Run the command : `python <yourpath>\script.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Comment: Could you explain ? I'm not sure what you mean . But here's what I'm working from http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html

Comment: @Marquavious How are you running your script?

Comment: I'm running it through IDLE. I have this particular script saved to my desktop and when I double click it flashes of course. I was using the program recommended from the lesson but it kept throwing me errors for this particular script .

Comment: Ok, for running with arguments, you cannot pass arguments. You need to open a command prompt and run the application as: `python script.py`

Comment: Ok, updated answer. Pass in three more values while running the script.

Comment: @Marquavious It is not code... it is another way of executing python programs.